# Why I don't need ToString() method inside a MessgeBox.Show ()

Tags: c#

I just noticed this works too:

```
MessageBox.Show("number of things in the report are  " + myHashSetVariable.Count);
```

I was under the impression that I should use myHashSetVariable.Count.ToString()

Is it some sort of Compiler/Interpreter improvments in VS2010?  I am using VS2010 Pro

Comment: `ToString` gets called implicitly because the first operator is a string type.

Comment: and that has *nothing* to do with the version of your development environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic .ToString()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759343/automatic-tostring) also [string = string + int: What's behind the scene?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398604/string-string-int-whats-behind-the-scene-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, this has nothing to do with `MessageBox.Show`.  This has everything to do with the `+` operator.  The result of string + object equals a string.

There are a number of overloads to the + operator in the language (and you can also add your own for user defined types).  There are only two that takes an `object` as a parameter, that is `operator+(string, object)` and `operator+(object, string)`.  In both cases the body of the implementation of the operator will call `ToString` on the `object` parameter and then use `string.Concat` to produce the result.

Since your variable is an integer and it is using `operator+` with `string` as the first parameter it will match `operator+(string, object)` an no other candidates.

Comment: Except that according to Jon Skeet, [the `+` operator is not overloaded on `string`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1788234/1106367). Rather, `+` *compiles down to `string.Concat`*.

Comment: @codesparkle Yes, the `+` operator is handled differently in the case of user-defined types than it is for a handful of native types, such a `string`.  While what happens after the particular overload is resolved is rather different, it will still use the same method-resolution rules to determine which overload of `operator +` to call.

Answer (score 2):

ToString is called implicitly to verify  you can omit the string literal in the message, Now you will need to explicitly call ToString to get rid of compilation error

```
MessageBox.Show(myHashSetVariable.Count); //This gives the error
```

Comment: @pst Well, for starters, most of the post was re-written after my comment, so I have removed it.  Next, as I have said in my answer, `MessageBox.Show` has nothing at all to do with this behavior; it has everything to do with the `+` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing this way:

```
int intval = 5;
string blah = "This is my string" + intval;
```

`ToString()` is called implicitly there. Though, I find it makes sense to call it explicitly, to make the code more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Servy's got it right. Here are a few links and examples that might help further your understanding the topics of string concatenation and implicit conversion.

The C# language specification section [7.7.4 Addition operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) states:

> The binary + operator performs string concatenation when one or both
>   operands are of type string. [...] any non-string argument is
>   converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual
>   ToString method inherited from type object.

For your simple case of the int predefined type, you're seeing an invocation of [int.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx) according to the specification. But if you have a user-defined type, you might also run into [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) conversion to string (gory details in [6.4.3 User-defined implicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691302%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

To experiment, define a method that mimics MessageBox.Show(string). It's important not to call [Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) directly, since it provides numerous overloads of Write, including Write(Int32):

```
static void Write(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

And a few user-defined classes:

First, an empty class with no overrides or conversions.

```
class EmptyClass {
}
```

And a class that overrides Object.ToString.

```
class ToStringOnly {
    public override string ToString() {
        return "ToStringOnly";
    }
}
```

Another class which demonstrates the implicit conversion to string:

```
class ImplicitConversion {
    static public implicit operator string(ImplicitConversion b) {
        return "Implicit";
    }
}
```

And finally, I wonder what happens when a class both defines an implicit conversion *and* overrides Object.ToString:

```
class ImplicitConversionAndToString {
    static public implicit operator string(ImplicitConversionAndToString b) {
        return "Implicit";
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return "ToString";
    }
}
```

A test for implicit conversions:

```
// Simple string, okay
Write("JustAString"); // JustAString

// Error: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'
//Write(2); 

// EmptyClass cannot be converted to string implicitly,
// so we have to call ToString ourselves. In this case
// EmptyClass does not override ToString, so the base class
// Object.ToString is invoked
//Write(new EmptyClass()); // Error
Write(new EmptyClass().ToString()); // StackOverflowCSharp.Program+EmptyClass

// implicit conversion of a user-defined class to string
Write(new ImplicitConversion()); // Implicit

// while ToStringOnly overrides ToString, it cannot be
// implicitly converted to string, so we have to again
// call ToString ourselves. This time, however, ToStringOnly
// does override ToString, and we get the user-defined text
// instead of the type information provided by Object.ToString
//Write(new ToStringOnly()); // ERROR
Write(new ToStringOnly().ToString());  // "ToStringOnly"
```

And, more relevant, a test for string concatenation:

```
// Simple string
Write("string"); // "string"

// binary operator with int on the right
Write("x " + 2); // "x 2"

// binary operator with int on the left
Write(3 + " x"); // "3 x"

// per the specification, calls Object.ToString
Write("4 " + new EmptyClass()); // "4 StackOverflowCSharp.Program+EmptyClass"

// the implicit conversion has higher precedence than Object.ToString
Write("5 " + new ImplicitConversion()); // "5 Implicit"

// when no implicit conversion is present, ToString is called, which
// in this case is overridden by ToStringOnly
Write("6 " + new ToStringOnly()); // "6 ToStringOnly"
```

And to seal it all up with a class that both defines an implicit conversion *and* overrides Object.ToString():

```
// In both cases, the implicit conversion is chosen
Write( new ImplicitConversionAndToString() ); // "Implicit"
Write( "8: " + new ImplicitConversionAndToString()); // 8: Implicit
```